# Unexpected end of expression

Tags: html, angularjs, treeview

I'm using [ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview) in my app, it works fine when defined like that:

```
<div ivh-treeview="frmMainCtrl.trvObGroups" style="height:100%"></div>
```

But, if I add some event handlers to it:

```
<div ivh-treeview="frmMainCtrl.trvObGroups" 
ivh-treeview-on-toggle="frmMainCtrl.onTrvToggle(ivhNode, ivhIsExpanded, ivhTree" 
ivh-treeview-on-cb-change="frmMainCtrl.onTrvCheck(ivhNode, ivhIsSelected, ivhTree)" 
style="height:100%"></div>
```

It throws an "unexpected end of expression" exception:

```
> Error: [$parse:ueoe]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$parse/ueoe?p0=frmMainCtrl.onTrvToggle(ivhNode%2C
> 0vhIsExpanded%2CvhTree
> O/<@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:6:412
> s.prototype.consume@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:228:26
> s.prototype.primary@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:225:43
> s.prototype.unary@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:223:406
> s.prototype.multiplicative@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:223:152
> s.prototype.additive@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:222:488
> s.prototype.relational@http://localhost:58395/rf/angular.min.js:222:323
```

I tried with and without spaces / tabs, those manipulations change nothing, maybe there is some expression length restriction in angular or what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `ivh-treeview-on-toggle="frmMainCtrl.onTrvToggle(ivhNode, ivhIsExpanded, ivhTree)"` why `)` is missing in your code.?

Comment: @sreeramu, because that's the case))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't close function call expression:

```
ivh-treeview-on-toggle="frmMainCtrl.onTrvToggle(ivhNode, ivhIsExpanded, ivhTree"
```

should be

```
ivh-treeview-on-toggle="frmMainCtrl.onTrvToggle(ivhNode, ivhIsExpanded, ivhTree)"
```

Comment: No problem, just fresh eye.